# Python xlwings copy-paste formula with relative cell references

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have a formula in cell A1 that is `"=C1+$D$1"`. I would like to use xlwings to copy paste this formula into A3 (keeping the relative cell reference). I would expect the pasted formula in cell A3 to be `"=C3+$D$1"` instead of `"=C1+$D$1"`.

Is there was a flag or function that would adjust the formula based on the range we're pasting to? If not, I guess the best solution would be to process the formula itself before pasting?

```
rng_to_paste = ws.range('A1').options(ndim=1).formula
ws.range('A3').options(ndim=1).formula = rng_to_paste
```

Comment: You are copy the Formula Value as is. Indeed you have to process the Formula itself or more simple assign a **new** Formula reflecting the current Row in your Example.

Answer (score 10):

Building on KrisG's answer, this works for me:

```
formula = xw.sheets[0].range("A1").formula
xw.sheets[0].range("A1,A3").formula = formula
```

Result:

```
     A
1    =C1+$D$1
2
3    =C3+$D$1
```

Basically, it's overwriting A1 with the same formula, but that gives it a point of reference so it knows how to modify the formula for A3.

Comment: This is brilliant. I confirm that it also works when you are copying ranges. It should be declared the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can assign the formula property of a range which will update the implicitly assigned cells in the range with the adjusted formula(s). However, with this method xlwings doesn't know where you copied the formula from, so it can only increment row/column relative to the assigned formula.

```
xw.sheets[0].range('A1:A5').value = [[i] for i in range(5)]
xw.sheets[0].range('B1:C5').formula = [['=A1+1','=B1*10']]

xw.sheets[0].range('A1:C5').value
Out[3]: 
[[0.0, 1.0, 10.0],
 [1.0, 2.0, 20.0],
 [2.0, 3.0, 30.0],
 [3.0, 4.0, 40.0],
 [4.0, 5.0, 50.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was to call an Excel macro to do the copy-paste for me. I had errors when trying to pass Worksheet and Range objects through to the macro so my code below uses just the string identifiers instead.

Python

```
def copypaste_range(wb_string,
                ws_source_string, 
                rng_to_copy_string, 
                ws_destination_string, 
                rng_to_paste_string):
import xlwings as xw
xw.App.display_alerts = False
folder = r'D:\My Documents'
xls_path = folder + r'\xlwings_macros.xlsb'
wb_macros = xw.Book(xls_path)
wb_macro = wb_macros.macro('copypaste_range')
wb_macro(wb_string,
         ws_source_string, 
         rng_to_copy_string, 
         ws_destination_string, 
         rng_to_paste_string)
xw.App.display_alerts = True
wb_macros.close()
```

VBA

```
Public Sub copypaste_range(wb_string, _
                       ws_source_string, rng_to_copy_string, _
                       ws_destination_string, rng_to_paste_string)

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
If Not IsWorkBookOpen(wb_string) Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=wb_string)
Else
    wb_string = fso.GetFileName(wb_string)
    Set wb = Workbooks(wb_string)
End If

Dim rng_to_copy As Range
Dim rng_to_paste As Range
Set rng_to_copy = wb.Sheets(ws_source_string).Range(rng_to_copy_string)
Set rng_to_paste = wb.Sheets(ws_destination_string).Range(rng_to_paste_string)

rng_to_copy.Copy _
    Destination:=rng_to_paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to handle this is using `copy` method of the `range`. `ws.range("A1").copy(ws.range("A3"))` - does the job.